# Group by two columns with case query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, common-table-expression, partition-by

I'm trying to retrieve drivers data with **Total Accepted** and **Total Ignored** ride requests for the current date.

Based on the `Drivers` and `DriverReceivedRequests` tables, I get the total count but the twists is I have duplicate rows that reside on the `DriverReceivedRequest` table against the `driverId` and the `rideId`. So there has to be group by clause on both the `driverId` and `RideId`, having the driver getting multiple requests for the current date, but also receiving twice or thrice request for the same ride as well.

This is the table structure for `DriverReceivedRequests`:

```
Id          DriverId       RideId         ReceivedStatusId     DateTime
------------------------------------------------------------------------
0014d26b    93665f55      fef6fb96            NULL              04:55.6
00175c65    6e62a94e      cb214a84            NULL              09:32.1
0017c22b    ec9e1297      4b47dc8a          4211357D            10:28:5
0014d26b    6e62a94e      fef6fb96            NULL              04:56.8
```

This is the query I have tried:

```
select 
    d.Id, d.FirstName, d.LastName,
    Sum(case when drrs.Number = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalAccepted,
    Sum(case when drrs.Number = 2 or drr.ReceivedStatusId  is null then 1 else 0 end) as TotalRejected
from 
    dbo.[DriverReceivedRequests] drr
inner join 
    dbo.[Drivers] d on drr.DriverId = d.Id
left join 
    dbo.[DriverReceivedRequestsStatus] drrs on drr.ReceivedStatusId = drrs.Id
where 
    Day(drr.Datetime) = Day(getdate())
    and month(drr.DateTime) = Month(getdate())
group by 
    d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.Id
```

In the above query if I group by with `RideId` as well, it generates duplicate names of drivers as well with incorrect data. I've also applied partition by clause with `DriverId` but not the correct result

This also generates the same result

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        d.Id, 
        d.FirstName, d.LastName, 
        TotalAccepted = SUM (CASE WHEN drrs.Number = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY drr.DriverId), 
        TotalRejected = SUM (CASE WHEN drrs.Number = 2 OR drr.ReceivedStatusId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                OVER (PARTITION BY drr.DriverId),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY drr.DriverId 
                               ORDER BY drr.DateTime DESC) 
    FROM   
        DriverReceivedRequests drr
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.[Drivers] d ON drr.DriverId = d.Id
    LEFT JOIN 
        dbo.[DriverReceivedRequestsStatus] drrs ON drr.ReceivedStatusId = drrs.Id
    WHERE  
        DAY (drr.Datetime) = DAY (GETDATE())
        AND MONTH (drr.DateTime) = MONTH (GETDATE())
) 
SELECT 
    Id, 
    FirstName, LastName, 
    TotalAccepted, TotalRejected
FROM
    cte 
WHERE  
    rn = 1
```

My question is how can I group by individual driver data in terms of incoming ride requests?

**Note**: the driver receives same ride request multiple times

Comment: Are you not wanting join DRRS as a subquery where the groupings / counts are done within the subquery?

Comment: Did that as well, but drrs has both the rideid and driverid. If i apply group by on driverid in the sub query, i would still get the incorrect results while apply group by on rideid on the external query.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to count every combination of  DriverId / RideId only once? What about cases where there are different states of ReceivedStatusId?

Comment: Thats where the result is incorrect. When I try to group just by driverid, the returned results gives me double incase there are two similar rideid for the same driver.